# Theme installation using Magento connect

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I have purchased theme in [theme link](https://themeforest.net/item/porto-ultimate-responsive-magento-theme/9725864)

i need to install the theme using magento connect

Comment: magento 1 or magento 2?

Comment: I don't think they offer installation like package. For installation you should check their user guide.

Comment: yes...you can upload the files via FTP

Comment: i am using magento 2.1.7.i trying to upload the files through  FTP but some file are not upload .so i will try other options @EwallTester

Comment: @RaviKumar: Allow folder permissions and upload your file

Comment: @RameshS: My server have folder permission as 775 but its not uploading

Comment: @RaviKumar : Ji check your `.htaccess` file  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292711/allow-safe-ftp-upload

Comment: I also did the same theme in magento 2, what error you are facing, can you send me the error in ftp once

Comment: @EwallTester: i have upload the files successfully.Thanks for the help

Comment: Hai @ Ewall Tester,I need help from you in that theme MagePlaza Layered Navigation Search is not working,left side bar working fine but the product result is not displaying.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged Magento 2.1.7 and provided link is redirecting to porto theme.

Here is installation documentation of Magento 2 porto theme you should follow this document and you able to intstall your theme.

http://newsmartwave.net/magento2/porto/documentation/